# Javascript HTTPS GET Restriction

Tags: javascript, https

I have made a script which I want the user to insert into their Url bar. The script is below.

```
javascript:x=new XMLHttpRequest();x.open("GET", "http://example.com/page.php?param1=value1&param2=value2", true); x.send()
```

The only problem is that the site I intend users to put that into their Url bar is an HTTPS site. For some reason it isn't working because of this. This is the error that I am getting in my Chrome Console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'example.net'; was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'example.com/page.php?param1=value1&param2=value2';. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Example.net is the 3rd party site & example.com is my site.

Anyway, is there a way to get past this error? I have been searching all day but with no success. Thanks.

Comment: Serve your content over HTTPS?

Comment: How would I do that through the Javascript?

Comment: Add an `s` after `http` in your URL, and configure your server.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the script fails is that the AJAX request will be run in the context of the current page. The next issue you'd likely run into is a CORS error even if you were serving your content via HTTPS.

Using the following is probably the safest bet but it'll redirect.

```
window.location = "http://example.com/page.php?param1=value1&param2=value2";
```

Something like this will also work but might get blocked by popup blockers:

```
var x = window.open("http://example.com/page.php?param1=value1&param2=value2");
```

Then if you want to close it after a bit then you could do something like

```
document.setTimeout(function(){
    x.close();

}, 4000);
```

The only other option I can think of which might work if none of these solutions are suitable is a browser plugin as that would allow you to execute JS in the context of the browser.

Comment: Would it be smart if I have my page redirect back to the original page once it has posted?

Comment: Quite probably - it really depends on what you're trying to achieve. If using `window.location` it might be worth using `history.back()` as opposed to another `window.location` or HTTP redirect to return to the page as this will minimize how the bookmark interferes with the page (forms partially filled, scripts etc.). I'd definitely test out the window.open method more first though as it's likely to be the least invasive - in Chrome at least when it's a bookmark it doesn't trigger the default popup blocker.

Answer (score 0):

You can proxy the request : the js call https://example.com/page.php and page.php in your back-end you call http://example.net/...